# how to disable apache,php cache?

Tags: php, apache, caching

I am having some problem with my apache-php server.
I didn't build up the web-app but all I need is to change some
text in php file.

the task was simple, however it is being ignored.
I grepped the text I modified, and saw that some cache file still contains
the original text. so I deleted the caches under '_apps/cache/' directory.
(cache file was cms_page_9)

but, even if I delete the cache files, it still comes up alive again
like zombies... I can't never delete those caches...
what am I missing here??

some advice would be nice.
thank you.

Comment: You can try this: delete the cache files, and then, restart de apache server for changes taking effects ;)

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work... I think this web application is really strange...

Comment: [Similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21700062/287948)